# Different definitions of Adjoint representation of SE(2)?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations, adjoint-operators

I have come across two different definitions of the Adjoint representation of SE(2) which similarly extends into SE(3):

$ \text{Ad}_{\mathbf{X}}= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{R} & 0_{3\times 3} \\ [\mathbf{p}_{1}]_{\times}\mathbf{R} & \mathbf{R}\end{bmatrix}$

and

$ \text{Ad}_{\mathbf{X}}= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{R} &  [\mathbf{p}_{1}]_{\times}\mathbf{R} \\ 0_{3\times 3} & \mathbf{R}\end{bmatrix}$

where $[\cdot]_{\times}$ denotes a skew-symmetrix.

What is the difference between the two?

Source for first representation: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06263

Source for second representation: http://ethaneade.com/lie.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental difference lies in the order of translation and rotation in se(3).

Specifically, for the first representation, se(3)=(w, t)^T, Rotate first and then translate;

for the second representation, se(3)=(t, w)^T, translate first and then Rotate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).